# What is the correct maven version for my proto branch?

Tags: maven, versioning

On a big project recently being built with maven3, we are currently working on our 4.1-SNAPSHOT branch for new developments to be delivered. 
But I need to create a 2nd branch where some experimental features are developed. These may or may not be back-integrated after a decision is being done at the end of the dev.
For this I usually create a new branch called "proto". I need this version to be in snapshot mode too and I try to choose a version that will be Maven compliant.
I consulted the Maven reference guide http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-syntax.html and resulted in "4.1-proto-01-SNAPSHOT".
Is that correct or may I lead into unforeseen conflicts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit more Maven would be "4.1.0-proto-01-SNAPSHOT", else it's okay.